# Next js 404 page not working in tsx extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have created a next js project with normal javaScript.This is my 404 page

**404.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function NotFound() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // router.go(1)
      router.push("/");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="not-found">
      <h1>Oooops!!!</h1>
      <p>
        Go back to home page
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Home page</a>
        </Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I created a seperate type script based next js project.

**404.tsx**

```
// import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Link from "next/link";

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Oh no!</h2>
      <p>There is not much left here for you</p>
      {/* <Link href="/">
        <a >Visit our home page</a>
      </Link> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotFound;
```

This is what I get in the typescript project.

[image]

What is wrong in the 404.tsx file?

Comment: Try deleting your `.next` folder then build and run the app again.

Answer (score 1):

It says that `client_dev_noop_js` module loading failed. There is nothing with **404.tsx**, however, it is better to name **_error.js** and **_error.tsx**